# How to make website app appear as Facebook bookmark?

Tags: facebook, bookmarks

I've created Facebook app, that only uses Website app, have authorized it and given permissions to it. It is well defined Game of subtype Adventure.
However, when I'm in Facebook, I don't see the game listed in the bookmarks.
How to make it appear there, once authorized by the user, no matter it is a web app with Facebook login, and currently does not have Facebook canvas app?

Comment: As far as I know only canvas apps have Facebook bookmarks.

Comment: @Malcolm well if this is the case how can I drive the user back to the application, if they quit and forget where they've been? I managed to find a reference to the app again, but it was in the App store and not quite obvious...